# Inspecting C# project in VS Package

Tags: visual-studio, mef

Is there a way to inspect active project in VS Package?

Currently I am using FileCodeModel, which has some basic support for code inspection, but for my needs this API is too limited. What would I like to do is somehow to link on C# compiler and read expression trees, like there are in Roslyn project.

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone else also wonders how to inspect currently hosted C# project and its references, here is the [link](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/retrieving-available-types-in-current-project-and-its-references-withoult-locking/) that I've found.

It seems that C# compiled result is never exposed directly through any API (I guess, like Roslyn).